# Cannot type cast or parse through data returned from POST request

Tags: arrays, json, swift3, network-programming

I'm working on a project where I'm using a POST request to get JSON data returned from an AWS server that my teammate set up.This is what my code looks like - pretty standard.

```
let task : URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if let data = data {
                    if let response = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(
                    with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {

                    let zones = response["body"]! as? [[String: Any]] ?? []
```

The JSON that gets returned looks like this

[image]

The content of "zones" isn't important here. What I want is the zones array, but it comes wrapped in this thing called "body" (my backend guy says that's just how AWS sends it over by default so it's not something he can change). The problem I'm having is the line I currently have that's supposed to get the zones array (`let zones = response["body"]! as? [[String: Any]] ?? []`) always gives me the empty array (and without `?? []` it gives me nil). If I get rid of the type casting, I get the zones array but it's of type `Any`, so I can't parse through it the way I want to. Any ideas on how to get the zones array as an array so I can parse it?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the value associated with the key `"body"`, which from the image is itself a dictionary not an array. Using the returned dictionary get the value associated with the key `"zones"`, this is the array you are after. HTH

Comment: Ohh yeah, you're right. But even when I do something like let body = response["body"] as? [String: Any] it just returns nil

Comment: Start at the top and check the value of each variable using the debugger or playground. Check values before you cast them if required. At some point you'll find you don't have what you expect. Good hunting!

Comment: Alright, thanks for the suggestion. I'll keep searching